# Using TextChanged listener on two relative text fields

Tags: java, android, listeners

This is my first question. I have very basic java training and I am developing a simple app in Android Studio right now. The app is a temperature converter that reads one TextField and after applying a method, it shows output in the other TextField in **Realtime**.

## So, here's what I'm doing:

[A screenshot of ActivityMain.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL4eG.png)

### The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText tc;
private EditText tf;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TempInC);
    tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TempInF);
```

So far so good. `tc` gets the input from *Temperature in Celsius* TextField, and `tf` gets input from *Temperature in Fahrenheit* TextField.

After that, I have:

```
            tc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String strTempCval = null;
                strTempCval = tc.getText().toString();
                if (strTempCval.isEmpty()) {
                    tf.setText(null);
                } else {
                    double tempCval = Double.parseDouble(strTempCval);
                    double ctofVal = toF(tempCval);
                    String fResult = String.valueOf(ctofVal);
                    tf.setText(fResult);
                }
            }
        });
```

This part takes the `tc` input, and converts it to fahrenheit by using `toF method` (in the MainActivity class, at the end), and show it in the `tf` TextField.

The next thing I want to do is the exact reverse of the above code, with the `tf input`, so here it goes:

```
tf.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    String strTempFval = tf.getText().toString();
                    if (strTempFval.isEmpty()) {
                        tc.setText(null);} else {
                        double tempFval = Double.parseDouble(strTempFval);
                        double ftocval = toC(tempFval);
                        String resultC = String.valueOf(ftocval);
                        tc.setText(resultC);
    }
            }
        });
}
```

### Now the problem is

...that if I'm using one of the above (either the one that *converts c to f*, or the one that *converts f to c*.), it works just fine (For example, if I comment out/disable one of these blocks). However, if I try to use both of the above functions simultaneously at the same time, the application crashes. Obviously because both TextChangedListeners are trying to manipulate/interact with each other.

Although, if required, the next part of the code is here: (The methods)

```
public double toC (double fVal){
    double cResult;
    cResult=(fVal-32)*5/9;
    return cResult;
}
public double toF (double cVal){
    double fResult = (cVal*9/5)+32;
    return fResult;
}
//MainActivity ends here.
```

Whew, so that's all the source code there. I hope someone can help me because I am very frustrated at this as I can't use OnKeyListener (intended for hard input). Any help would be highly appreciated as I have been stuck at it for days! A bundle of thanks in advance for anyone who is willing to help me!

Comment: Can you please post the logcat error when the app crashes? Can't tell what's wrong exactly without the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will be getting a stackOverflowException which is because it goes into infinite loop

so use hasFocus() like this to solve your problem, as only the EditText beings edited by the user will have focus. do this for both EditTexts

```
tf.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if(tf.hasFocus()) {                
                String strTempFval = tf.getText().toString();
                if (strTempFval.isEmpty()) {
                    tc.setText(null);
                } else {
                    double tempFval = Double.parseDouble(strTempFval);
                    double ftocval = toC(tempFval);
                    String resultC = String.valueOf(ftocval);
                    tc.setText(resultC);
                }
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! You're a life saver. It's working fine now!